# Webpack build issue with mobx and mobx-react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mobx, mobx-react

I have a project that uses React and Mobx with Mobx-react.

My project runs perfectly fine locally. However, when built using `webpack -p`, I get a blank screen with the following error in the console:

```
webpack:///./~/mobx-react/index.js?:3 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "mobx"
    at webpackMissingModule (webpack:///./~/mobx-react/index.js?:3)
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (webpack:///./~/mobx-react/index.js?:3)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/mobx-react/index.js?:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:18)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/components/Category.jsx?:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:27)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/components/CategoryNavsDates.jsx?:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:14)
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/');
var SOURCE_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: SOURCE_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true, importLoaders: 1, localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:3] "} },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {} },
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: function () {
          return [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('postcss-cssnext'),
          ];
        },
      }
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'index.html', to: '' },])
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
};
```

There is only one file using Mobx in my entire project, and that is the file the error refers to, `Category.jsx`.

`Category.jsx` sample:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import { observable } from 'mobx'
...
@observer class Category extends React.Component {
  @observable showingSmallMenu = false
  ...
}
```

As I say this all works perfectly fine locally.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: did you install `mobx` as `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies` ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it make a difference if you import `mobx` before `mobx-react`?

Comment: The same error shows, except this time it comes from `index.js` rather than `mobx-react`:

`if(true)
  module.exports = factory(__webpack_require__(2), __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"mobx\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';; throw e; }())), __webpack_require__(76));
 else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
  define(["react", "mobx", "react-dom"], factory);
...`

Comment: what does index.js look like?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that is caused by:

```
alias: {
   mobx: __dirname + '/node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.es6.js'
}
```

Remove mobx alias, then the problem is solved